# О разных кранах

Tags: омонимы

Подумалось: а что общего, кроме названия, у водопроводного крана и подъемного? Почему и то, и другое - кран, если они выполняют совершенно разные функции?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Я абсолютно согласен с предыдущим оратором, хотя, если честно, ни слова из его объяснения не понял. У меня есть ответ чисто ассоциативный. Можно попробовать вывести этимологию через журавля. В родном всем нам с детства английском языке журавль - "крэйн", что очень созвучно с краном, да и функционально колодец-журавль является краном. Как подъёмным, так и наполняющим систему водой(вспомним древние египетские оросительные конструкции). Теперь можно подсмотреть гугло-русско-латинский переводчик и увидеть, что журавль и кран обозначаются одним и тем же словом "docet". QED

Answer (score 0):

Названия некоторых технических приспособлений имеют "животное" происхождение: журавль, лебедка, баран (стенобитное орудие). К таким названиям относится и слово "кран" в обоих своих значениях: функции  у них, действительно, разные, но оба они напоминают шею журавля или петуха.

Оба слова пришли к нам в начале 18 века, например: "... за дело трех моделей подъемных судов и кранов (Книга приходов и расходов за 1714 г.), "...крант палмовый с медными винтами (из бумаг Я. Брюса по описи 1735 г.)

Кран - это заимствование из голландского языка: "kraan" - кран, от Kran - нижненемецкое, старшее значение - "журавль", сравнить: Kranich - "журавль" в современном  немецком языке.